# Como remover definitivamente um projeto no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Gostaria de remover definitivamente um projeto do Android Studio, percebo que na página inicial abaixo, se estiver com um projeto selecionado e apertar Delete, o projeto é removido da lista, porém ainda encontro ele na minha pasta de projetos. Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira mais prática, pelo próprio Android Studio, de remover definitivamente o projeto. Obrigado!

[image: Imagem inicial do Android Studio]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, há uma maneira pelo Android Studio.

Com o seu projeto aberto, clique com o botão direito do mouse no seu projeto, na barra de projetos e selecione "Deletar".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando abrir o Android Studio novamente, basta remover o projeto da lista dos projetos recentes.

Comment: O que você chama de **Barra de Projetos** é na verdade a **Navigation Bar**.

Comment: Sim, sei disso. Mas obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Vá na pasta onde os projetos do Android Studio são salvos, **exemplo:**

C:\Work\SEUNOME\NOME_DO_PROJETO

Dentro dessa pasta, exclua o projeto que você queira e pronto.

Então na próxima vez que você entrar no Android Studio, o projeto removido não vai mais aparecer na lista.

Comment: Isso eu já sei.... Minha dúvida é se teria uma maneira diferente, pelo próprio Android Studio. Mesmo assim, obrigado pela contribuição

Answer (score -1):

Atualizando Resposta para o post v.2022
Botão Direito no nome do projeto (canto superior Direito) [Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APDXn.png)